# k-means for text clustering

Tags: algorithm, k-means

I'm trying to implement k-means for text clustering, specifically English sentences. So far I'm at the point where I have a term frequency matrix for each document (sentence). I'm a little confused on the actual implementation of k-means on text data. Here's my guess of how it should work.

1. Figure out the number of unique words in all sentences (a large number, call it `n`).
2. Create `k` `n` dimensional vectors (clusters) and fill in the values of the `k` vectors with some random numbers (how do I decide what the bounds for these numbers are?)
3. Determine the Euclidean distance from each of the `q` sentences to the random `k` clusters, reposition clusters, etc. (If `n` is very large like the English language, wouldn't calculating the Euclidean distance for these vectors be very costly?)

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment.

If you have a document term matrix, then find the principal components (of the covariance matrix). Determine the coefficients of the original data in the principal component space.  You can do k-means clustering in this space.

With text data, you generally need a bunch of dimensions -- 20, 50, 100, or even more.  Also, I would recommend Gaussian mixture models/expectation-maximization clustering instead of k-means, but that is another story.

Answer (score 1):

resurrecting a slightly old question here, but worth linking the two...

Generally, you'd use some kind of locally-sensitive hashing instead of relying on frequency of word occurrence. But either way, manually assembling the feature matrix is a huge hassle.

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48721478/3556110) gives you a guide to how to create that feature matrix from a list of documents, using scikit-learn and explaining the steps. I think it'll help show you the sequence of steps required.