# k-means using signature matrix generated from minhash

Tags: python, text, cluster-analysis, k-means, minhash

I have used minhash on documents and their shingles to generate a signature matrix from these documents. I have verified that the signature matrices are good as comparing jaccard distances of known similar documents (say, two articles about the same sports team or two articles about the same world event) give correct readings.

**My question is: does it make sense to use this signature matrix to perform k-means clustering?**

I've tried using the signature vectors of documents and calculating the euclidean distance of these vectors inside the iterative kmeans algorithm and I always get nonsense for my clusters. I know there should be two clusters (my data set is a few thousands articles about either sports or business) and in the end my two clusters are always just random. I'm convinced that the randomness of hashing words into integers is going to skew the distance function every time and overpower similar hash values in two signature matrices.

[Edited to highlight the question]

Comment: So basically, you're computing k-means clusters but you've got too many clusters at the end. One janky solution would be to just take 1 "gold standard" sports document and then sort everything into 1 of 2 buckets based on distance from that one. 

Another option is to look into basic machine learning. This would be really easy to train since the only 2 outcomes are business or sports.

Comment: Not too many clusters, more that it just seems random docs are being assigned to either cluster 0 or 1. I'm only using k=2 so only 2 clusters are possible. But when computing distances of all articles from centers, the distances are more based on random hashes than actual similar words. I tried just pikcing two initial articles, 1 from sports and 1 from business and just comparing the jaccard distance of every other article to these and then just using that as my clusters (and this works very well) but that's not what I was asked to do. I was asked to use signature matrix for iterative kmeans

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL;DR

Short answer: No, it doesn't make sense to use the signature matrix for K-means clustering. At least, not without significant manipulation.

### Some explanations

I'm coming at this after a few days of figuring out how to do the same thing (text clustering) myself. I might be wrong, but my perception is that you're making the same mistake I was: using MinHash to build an `[n_samples x n_perms]` matrix, then using this as a features matrix `X` on which you run k-means.

I'm guessing you're doing something like:

```
# THIS CODE IS AN EXAMPLE OF WRONG! DON'T IMPLEMENT!
import numpy as np
import MinHash
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
# Get your data. 
data = get_your_list_of_strings_to_cluster()
n_samples = len(data)
# Minhash all the strings
n_perms = 128
minhash_values = np.zeros((n_samples, n_perms), dtype='uint64')
minhashes = []
for index, string in enumerate(data):
    minhash = MinHash(num_perm=n_perms)
    for gram in ngrams(string, 3):
         minhash.update("".join(gram).encode('utf-8'))
     minhash_values[index, :] = minhash.hashvalues
# Compute clusters
clusterer = KMeans(n_clusters=8)
clusters = clusterer.fit_predict(minhash_values)
```

This will behave **horribly** because of the fateful flaw - the `minhash_values` array is **not** a feature matrix. Each row is basically a list of features (hashes) which appear in that sample of text... but they're not column-aligned so features are scattered into the wrong dimensions.

To turn that into a *feature* matrix, you'd have to look at all the unique hashes in `minhash_values` then create a matrix which is `[n_samples x n_unique_hashes]`, (`n_unique_hashes` is the number of unique features found) setting it to `1` where the text sample contains that feature, `0` elsewhere. Typically this matrix would be large and sparse. You could then cluster on that.

### Alternative way of text clustering

What an unbelievable hassle though! Fortunately, `scikit-learn` is there to help. It provides some very [easy to use and scalable vectorisers](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.feature_extraction.text):

So your problem becomes easily solved:

```
# Imports
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

# Get your data
data = get_your_list_of_strings_to_cluster()

# Get your feature matrix
text_features = HashingVectorizer(analyzer="word").fit_transform(data)

# Compute clusters
clusterer = KMeans(n_clusters=2)
clusters = clusterer.fit_predict(text_features)
```

And there you go. From there:

- Fine tune your vectoriser (try TfidfVectorizer too, tweak the input params, etc),
- Try other clusterers (f/ex I find
  [HDBSCAN](http://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) *miles* better
  than kmeans - quicker, more robust, more accurate, less tuning).

Hope this helps.

Tom

Comment: For latest version of sklearn (0.19.1) use from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer instead of  from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectoriser

Comment: I think it must've always been that way. Fixing the typo. Thanks @Bhargav